# SQL Server2008: BeginExecuteNonQuery / EndExecuteNonQuery Problem

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a **stored procedure**, which writes a backup of a specific database. I call this SP in a C# / Windows Forms application asynchrounously. Here is the code snipped:

```
IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
     ...
}
command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result));
```

After some time the program leaves the loop, because IsCompleted = true and calls EndExecuteNonQuery.
The problem now is, that the Job is still busy and **EndExecuteNonQuery** is **blocked**!
This causes a **server timeout** after some minutes.
It seems that the **IsCompleted** value is not consistent respectively what's wrong with **IsCompleted**?
How can I achieve that my program recognizes the **"real job status"**?

Comment: Is there a  reason why you don't use the callback overload for BeginExecuteNonQuery  and wait for the callback to be called before calling EndExecuteNonQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your stored procedure does not print anything and has no count reports (`SET NOCOUNT ON`). Async TDS calls call back at the *very first* packet sent by the server, but this packet might be a intermediate result (as in `1 row updated`) and happen long, long before the actual completion. Does this suck? Yes. Can you do anything about it? No.

As a side note, is it infinitely more efficient to just pass a callback to the BeginExecute(...):

```
// Set form's state to 'executing', 
// eg. Button.Enabled = false; label.Text = 'Executing';
command.BeginExecuteNonQuery((asyncstate)=>
{
   try
   {
      command.EndExecuteNotQuery();
   }
   catch(SqlException ex)
   {
     ...
   } 
   // Reset the form's state to 'Ready'
   Invoke (()=>
   {
     // eg. Button.Enabled = true; label.Text = 'Ready';
   }
}
```